# Moved A Database And Now Stored Procedures Run Slowly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm moving a database backup from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2005.

The hardware they are running on is equivalent.

In light of that, shouldn't the stored procedures, while running on SSQL2005, run at least as fast (if not faster)? The data is *exactly* the same. However, they run 5x slower.

I reindexed the database and reset its statistics after restoring it to SSQL2005.

Dumbfounded.....

FYI, when making the dump files, I made sure that they were checksummed and verified.

I created 2 separate backups and did this with 2 backups and got the same result.

Comment: Have you tried running them more than once?  There's a very good chance your old server was benefiting from page caching, which the new machine can't yet (since the data just got there).

Comment: Thanks JNK for responding. I ran each Stored Procedure multiple times, and there was barely any change in the running time.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand - I ran this script. <BR/>                              <pre>USE POS_PROD<BR/>
GO<BR/>
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?' DBCC DBREINDEX ('?', ' ', 80)"<BR/>
GO<BR/>
EXEC sp_updatestats
GO</pre>

Comment: Yikes, you should add that to the question with formatting, impossible to read as a comment. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of differences between SQL Server 2000 and 2005.  So this is certainly not impossible.

Assuming the data and indexes are all the same, I would first look at the execution plans of a representative procedure - if they differ, then there is something which needs to be investigated there, and that could include parameter sniffing issues.

If all that pans out, then next you'll probably need to dig into the file locations to see if the data and log files are set up differently in terms of drives and underlying RAID etc.  Then on to performance counters etc.

Update:
try T switch 4199, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx for available switches etc. Also make sure you ahve installed the latest cumulative update pack.

Comment: Thanks Cade. I wanted to know if there was some better way, but it seems the best way is to look at and interpret execution plans.

Comment: @bluerain Well, you only have to start with the same one on each side.  This is usually the "deepest" first step on anything I'm not happy with performance (after checking that the tables are even indexed at all and the query isn't doing something stupid).  You said it was a backup and restore, but it probably couldn't hurt to make sure the indexes are there in the schema.

Comment: I checked that all indexes matched.

Comment: In addition to checking the hardware variables above, check that the network setting & configuration are the same on both machines.  I've had that problem.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you update the compatibility level of the database:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90;
```

Also make sure you update statistics on (or rebuild) your indexes.

And of course you'll want to make sure SQL Server 2005 is all patched up - have you installed [Service Pack 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7218) and the [latest Cumulative Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2507769)?

Comment: Aaron - I tried this and got no improvement. However, it was important that I did it.

Comment: Why should I put the latest SP if no fix listed on the Service Pack promises to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually - from my time at Microsoft SQL Server Level 3 Support- there are a number of issue,s one of them forcing a 2000 database to run EXTREMELY slow in 2005. It is an issue with the query optimizer IIRC (3 years ago) Ignoring the cost of setting up a table scan and - thus seeing a small table scan as low cost, which it is expensive (lots of overhead) so looping around that. I remember a case that took a query to "never finishes" In 2005.

There is a switch for startup to force the old behavior, but I do not remember it. Trying to find it now.

Comment: Thanks, TomTom. I think I'll be figuring out how to create and read sql execution plans.